# Project a circle onto a square?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an [photograph of a retina](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fundus_photograph_of_normal_right_eye.jpg) stored as a numpy array. I'll represent this image with this 2D numpy array (my actual array is much bigger, has 3 color channels and the values are floats, not all `0` or `1`):

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

How can I project the circle (stretch the edges somehow?) so that it becomes a square without getting cropped? So that it looks like this:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Basically, I'm looking for a Python library that can do the conformal mapping in this image

[image: conformal mapping from circle to square]

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1206995)  on math.stackexchange might help. You may need to do some rounding.

Comment: Have a look at [cmtoolkit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cmtoolkit/0.0.1)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`squircle`](https://github.com/verhovsky/squircle) for this (disclaimer: I wrote it)

```
import squircle
import PIL
import numpy as np

square = np.asarray(Image.open('some-square-image.jpg'))  # or create the array some other way

circle = squircle.to_circle(square, method="fgs")
and_back_to_square = squircle.to_square(circle, method="fgs")
```

there's 3 different methods for transforming circles/squares: `"fgs"`, `"stretch"` and `"elliptical"`

It doesn't handle ellipses and rectangles, but you can do that by upsampling the image, naively squishing it into a square, running squircle on it and unsquishing it back into a rectangle.

You can install it with

```
pip install squircle
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the maximum and minimum indices of none-zero elements in row and column to get the scope of your 1's then fill your array indices based on this scope :

```
>>> a=np.array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
...        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
...        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
...        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
...        [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
...        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
...        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
...        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
...        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> 
>>> (min_row,max_row),(min_col,max_col)=map(lambda x :(np.min(x),np.max(x)),np.nonzero(a))
>>> a[min_row:max_row+1,min_col:max_col+1]=1
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```